# How does this js code work?

Tags: javascript

```js
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
  foo = 10;
  return;
  function foo() {}
}
bar();
console.log(foo);
```

I don't understand why this code outputs `1`

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You have `foo = 1` and you are logging the value of `foo` (which is `1`). I guess you mean you are confused as to why `foo = 10` doesn't overwrite it? Well that's because `foo` in the scope of `bar` is a **different** variable. This is caused by the declaration of the `foo` method... perhaps do some research into "hoisting"

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze no, `foo` in the function is the local symbol created by the nested function declaration.

Comment: What would you expect the output to be?

Comment: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting.html

Comment: it has to do with nested function because if you remove it it prints 10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside of your function bar, you are defining a function `foo` that will be defined hoisted inside of your function, which means the body of your function is pretty much like:

```
function bar() {
  function foo() {}
  foo = 10;
  return;
}
```

This function is scoped inside of the body of bar so it's pretty similar to

```
function bar() {
  var foo = function foo() {};
  foo = 10;
  return;
}
```

This means that when you're modifying `foo`, you're not modifying your global var but only the one scoped inside of `bar`.

Answer (score 6):

Function declarations:

- Are hoisted
- Create a local variable (just like `var`) with a matching name

So `function foo` creates a local variable `foo` before `foo = 10` overwrites it with a number.

Since the variable is local, nothing inside the function touches the global variable which is also called `foo` so it is set to `1` on line 1 and never changes.